# Dynamically add link with String parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a REST backend link `mywebsite/guests`, which returns list of guests. In the front end, I want to display the guests as links. Here's the code

```
for(guest of guests) {
  $('#guest_list').append('<a onclick="showGuest(' + guest.id + ')">' + guest.name + '</a><br>')
}

function showGuest(id) {
  console.log(id)
  ...
}
```

I should mention that `guest.id` is a string.

The console always print `undefined`. My question, how can I add these links with String parameters?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(guest)` inside  that for-loop and share the results with us?

Comment: `guest of guests` ??

Comment: try `for(var guest in guests)`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(guest of guests) {
  $('#guest_list').append('<a onclick="showGuest(this)" data-id='+guest.id+'>' + guest.name + '</a><br>')
}

function showGuest(this) {

console.log($(this).data('id'))
}
```

Comment: id of guest in my case is `string`.

Comment: let it be you can store it in data attrib

Answer (score 0):

The way to approach this problem depends on the format and content of the `guests` variable. If you started with this object:

```
var guests = {
  '123': {id: 123, name: 'joe'},
  '234': {id: 234, name: 'jane'}
};
```

Then `key` would be "123" and "234" in the following loop, and the object values would be `guests[key]`:

```
for(var key in guests) {
  $('#guest_list').append('<a onclick="showGuest(' + guests[key].id + ')">' + guests[key].name + '</a><br>')
}

function showGuest(id) {
  console.log(id)
  ...
}
```

But if you're already using jQuery, take a look at [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for another looping option.

---

On the other hand, if `guests` is an array, as in:

```
var guests = [
  {id:"123", name:"joe"},
  {id:"234", name:"jane"}
];
```

then you will just want to use something like:

```
for(var i=0; i < guests.length; i++) {
  // id is guests[i].id
  // name is guests[i].name
}
```

Comment: In my case, id of guests is string.

Comment: That's fine, number or string won't matter here. But is `guests` an object (as in my example) or is it an array? e.g. `var guests = [{id:"123", name:"joe"}, {id:"234", name:"jane"}]` note the surrounding `[]`

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you are trying to access the property of dynamically bound DOM elements in your `showGuest(id)` function. You should use the `onClick` function in the following way-

```
var guests = [{"id":1, "name":"John Doe"}, 
                {"id":2, "name":"David Jones"}];

for(guest of guests) {
    $('#guest_list').append('<a class="guest" data-id="'+guest.id+'">' + guest.name + '</a><br>');
}

$('#guest_list').on('click', 'a.guest', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.message').text('').append("Clicked guest with ID: "+id);
});
```

Working JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/2dkpsve8/

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is certainly the better way to handle click events

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly,

`$('#guest_list').append('<a onclick="showGuest(' + "guest.id" + ')">' + guest.name + '</a><br>')`

works fine! I don't know way. `"guest.id"` is replaced by the actual id of guest.